Magento Tier Price is Restored After Deleted from Database
I need to delete the products non global tier prices.
So I deleted the non global tier price data from database using query delete from catalog_product_entity_tier_price where website_id!=0 and done cache clear and reindexed
But the tier price values are restored again.
